# Delete element from div in div with a button generated from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application with a page where users can post messages on. These messages are retrieved from the database in which they are stored on forehand in my pageload section in code behind. For each message a new div is generated with in there another div for the message and one for the username. A button is made for each individual post, and the problem is that I want the button to remove a post (thus the message in the database) from the div. But I can't figure out how to do it since everything is generated in code behind. Maybe FindControl() can help?

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);               
            conn.Open();
            queryStr = "SELECT berichtID ,bericht, user FROM tblforum ORDER BY berichtID DESC";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
            MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try {
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                ImageButton Button = new ImageButton();
                Button.ImageUrl = "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-gear-512.png";
                HtmlGenericControl User = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                HtmlGenericControl Div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                HtmlGenericControl Username = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
                HtmlGenericControl Message = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
                Button.Style.Add("max-height", "inherit");
                Button.Style.Add("width", "auto");
                Button.Style.Add("float", "right");
                Username.InnerText = Reader["user"].ToString() + " said: ";
                Div.Style.Add("border-bottom", "6px solid black");
                Div.Style.Add("background-color", "#006633");
                Message.Style.Add("color", "#d3d3d3");
                forumsection.Controls.Add(Div);
                Message.InnerText = Reader["bericht"].ToString();
                Div.Controls.Add(User);
                User.Controls.Add(Button);
                User.Controls.Add(Username);
                Div.Controls.Add(Message);
            }
            Reader.Close();
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll want to show some code that explains what you've tried and what isn't working. Generally, a div is not a server side control so it will require some additional effort to make it visible to server side code. It sounds like you're trying to emulate a data bound control like a repeater or gridview. You may do better to investigate these as options for displaying your data.

Comment: Updated, and yes, I want the data to be bound like a gridview, but then without it.

To visualize: http://gipa3.ga/Gastenboek.aspx

Comment: So you want the button to remove the associated div AND issue a DELETE command to the database?

Comment: Yes you got that right

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayData();
        }

        private void DisplayData()
        {
            //your code
            string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            queryStr = "SELECT berichtID ,bericht, user FROM tblforum ORDER BY berichtID DESC";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
            MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    ImageButton Button = new ImageButton();                        
                    Button.ImageUrl = "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-gear-512.png";
                    //**************ADD THIS TO FIRE DELETE*************
                    Button.Click += Button_Click;
                    Button.ID = "btnForDBItem_" + Reader.GetOrdinal("berichtID").ToString();
                    //**************END OF FIRE DELETE*****************
                    HtmlGenericControl User = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    HtmlGenericControl Div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    HtmlGenericControl Username = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
                    HtmlGenericControl Message = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
                    Button.Style.Add("max-height", "inherit");
                    Button.Style.Add("width", "auto");
                    Button.Style.Add("float", "right");
                    Username.InnerText = Reader["user"].ToString() + " said: ";
                    Div.Style.Add("border-bottom", "6px solid black");
                    Div.Style.Add("background-color", "#006633");
                    Message.Style.Add("color", "#d3d3d3");
                    forumsection.Controls.Add(Div);
                    Message.InnerText = Reader["bericht"].ToString();
                    Div.Controls.Add(User);
                    User.Controls.Add(Button);
                    User.Controls.Add(Username);
                    Div.Controls.Add(Message);
                }
                Reader.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //add your database code to do the DELETE here
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
            var IDtoDELETE = btn.ID.Replace("btnForDBItem_",""); 
            //now call DisplayData() to regenerate the page without the deleted item
            DisplayData();
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the id or string of the Message <p> to put in the MySQL statement?

Also, can you explain why you set the ID to null?

Comment: What i've actually done if you look where I originally assign the ID of the Button in the DisplayData function, is name it "btnForDBItem_X" where X = the ID from the database column "berichtID" which was just my guess as to what your primary key column is you'll want to delete. The btn.ID.Replace in Button_Click is just stripping off all the unnecessary text from the clicked button's ID so you have the raw ID you need to craft your delete SQL.